# Magento2 - Google Pagespeed Insight : any idea why it takes account of desktop css?

Tags: magento2, template, css, pagespeed-insights

My question might not be magento specific, but I'm curious, as I couldn't find the answer elsewhere (or failed to find the correct terms).

When I use Google Pagespeed Insight on a magento 2 website with a template based on the basic one (or Luma), it says :

Remove unused CSS

…css/styles-l.min.css

But the code for the link to this CSS is :

```html
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" href="https://www.magento2-website.com/static/versionxxxx/frontend/Template/base/fr_FR/css/styles-l.min.css" />
```

So it's supposed to be only use if width is more than 768px.

Any idea why Pagespeed thinks it have to be taken account ?

Thanks !

Edit : add Insight to be more specifis. The problem is not with mod_pagespeed, but with the fact that Pagespeed Insight takes account of a file that it shouldn't

Comment: @ChrisRosenau yes I know that. That's not my question. And even if you remove unused CSS in your styles-l.css, it will still be taken account in the mobile tab of insights no ? And defering CSS is also a technique, but again, that's not my question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser downloads all CSS resources, regardless of the media attribute. Check your network tab on your site and you'll notice even on mobile devices it downloads styles-l.css.

The media attribute allows the user agent to pick the best adapted one for the device it runs on, in other words it will de-prioritise styles-l.css which helps prevent it from blocking the rendering of the DOM but it will still be downloaded.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Attributes and https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css are good resources on this.

Comment: Ok, so I guess that's not how to do it and default Luma is not good for PS Ranking. Thanks a lot for your answer